# ReportViewer in WPF behaving differently on similar machines

Tags: wpf, parameters, reportviewer, local, credentials

I have a reportviewer control in a pop up window inside my WPF application. When the report is to be printed, on some client machines it gives the following message "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified". 
This error **does not come on every client machine** even though the machines are identical in every respect.

I have tried the explicit refresh on the local report as well as all the options mentioned when a similar question has been posted.
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I have this issue too. Not in WPF, just in WinForms, but exact same mesage and only on some machines. Are you installing the ReportViewer redistributable or are you just shipping the DLLs? Or even better... have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like this:

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Change it to:

`ReportViewer.LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence)`

This latter routine says it's obsolete but it makes that error message go away... at least it does in my testing so far!!

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 Reports (rdcl) in the same XAML.

I was having this same problem when I wanted to change datasource, after a button click.

After I've moved both refreshes to the end of the click function, never got this message again and everything is working fine.

```
this.viewerGraphic.RefreshReport();
this.viewerInstance.RefreshReport();
```